# using python to collect remote server (linux) metrics

Tags: python, linux, centos, fabric

I'm trying to find out the best approach in collecting the metrics on a remote linux machine using python scripting. Based on online readings i have configured fabric & able to run commands on the remote server.

But the challenging part is entering the password on every run & it won't help if we schedule the process. There are two options i have found,

1. hardcode the account password in env.password (with this approach
   are there any security concerns & will this approach work with cron
   schedule).
2. generate ssh keys for user account for authentication (with this
   approach are there any security concerns & I have noticed if the
   cron job is scheduled under sudo it fails).
3. any other best approaches available to gather the metrics remotely
   using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hardcoding a password is never really a great solution, even if it's an environment variable. Using ssh keys is much better, and the security concerns are minimal. I would recommend using [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) - it wraps ssh so you don't have to do anything fancy to authenticate. I also think it's a bit more widely used than fabric. I haven't used fabric in years but from what I've seen I think ansible is a bit more flexible.